# Can my question about RapidXML be migrated to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-declined, migration, specific-question

Could someone please reopen then migrate [{RapidXML} Cannot open XML files unless in main](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117615/) to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

You were banned from Stack Overflow for asking too many off-topic questions: because of that, [we won't migrate your questions there anymore](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/using-programmers-to-side-step-the-rules-on-stack-overflow). For more information about this ban, please check out the Meta Stack Overflow question, [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi).

It appears you're very close to getting unbanned: to ensure that happens, you'll need to do two things:

1. **Stop asking off-topic questions here and on Stack Overflow.** Please [read the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and heed moderators' advice and warnings: you've asked a number of questions here that do not belong on Programmers and and a number on Stack Overflow that don't belong there, either.
2. **Start answering questions on Stack Overflow.** You only need a few more up-votes to be able to ask questions: you'll get those by paying it forward and helping others out with their problems. Be sure to answer questions that are on-topic there: answering off-topic questions will wind up penalizing you as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've been answering as many questions as I can on Stack Overflow. How many points am I off?

Comment: @AT To prevent people gaming the system, we won't disclose that level of detail. If you keep providing high quality answers there, you should be able to ask questions again in no time.