# How many questions do we get from users recently blocked at SO, how many of these are closed / deleted?

Tags: support, closed-questions, stackoverflow, post-ban, user-accounts

Recent efforts in SO close vote queue make me think that quite a lot of users started hitting the question ban there.

There is [long known "tradition"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112598/165773) of attempts to circumvent such bans by posting at inappropriate sites:

> The core issue here seems to be the abusive "I can't ask any more, so I'll ask my question on a similar site, in the hope it is migrated"...

I wonder how much impact could this have on Programmers. To understand this, I would like to find out how many questions per day are posted by users that were banned at SO less than a month ago, and how many of these questions end up closed / deleted?

It would be also helpful to learn similar statistics for questions from users who:

- aren't *yet* banned, but are already [warned about approaching a ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773) at SO
- are rate-limited to ask questions at SO by [anti-recidivism system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773)

---

Basically I am trying to figure whether it's something that can be dealt with in our regular ways, or it is worth looking for a dedicated approach to address (like, say, system triggering automated flag for mod attention when post from such a user gets close vote / flag).

Related:

- (MSO) [Let's burn down the close queue!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue)

  - (MSE) [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination)
  - (MSE) [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773)
  - (MSE) [What is the reasoning behind limiting "recidivists" to post one question per week?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234609/165773)
  - (MSO) [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543/839601)
- (MSE) [Stats on how attempts to circumvent SO question blocks impact other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237540/165773)
- (Meta P.SE) [Provide 10k users more close votes](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/provide-10k-users-more-close-votes)

Comment: I am not sure that we can see even as mods who is banned from asking questions on another site.  I am also not sure that we can tell using [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com), at least not without knowing the algorithm they use for banning.  I often don't realize the OP is banned until AFTER I attempt to migrate.

Comment: @maple_shaft to the best of my knowledge, such data is available only to SE devs. In particular, aggregate data on deleted questions I am looking for is [currently not available in SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se "see at MSO: 'Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE'")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform automatic checks for cross-posting and question ban at SO when post enters close queue, not only at attempt to migrate](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/perform-automatic-checks-for-cross-posting-and-question-ban-at-so-when-post-ente)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aXfX2.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While running a [test on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science), there were some questions about whether we were driving traffic to Programmers, so I decided to rerun some of the numbers in [Shog’s original answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7332/28602) and compare the 30 days prior to the test to the testing period.

### Prior to the Stack Overflow Test

First, let's look at the 30 days of activity here on Programmers prior to the start of the test, the time period was **February 15, 2016 to March 16, 2016**.  During this time there were:

- **1452** questions asked here, from
- **1283** distinct account, of which
- **1143** have/has account on Stack Overflow
- **298** of these users hit some sort of block on Stack Overflow in the 30 days.

From those 298 users:

- **354** questions were posted
- **200** were closed
- **244** were deleted
- **233** scored < 0
- **124** had at least one answer
- **74** scored > 0

For comparison:

- **701** questions were closed in total
- **843** were deleted
- **801** scored < 0
- **596** had at least one answer
- **434** scored > 0

Looking into the details, I also checked the IP addresses associated with these posts to see how many came from blocked address on Stack Overflow. Of the IP Addresses, 288 hit some sort of block on Stack Overflow. From those addresses:

- **339** questions were posted here
- **185** were closed
- **216** were deleted
- **208** scored < 0
- **128** had at least one answer
- **81** scored > 0

### During the Test Period (March 16, 2016 - April 13, 2016)

The numbers over the test were:

- **1388** questions asked, from
- **1202** distinct account, of which
- **1087** have/has account on Stack Overflow
- **248** of these users hit some sort of block on Stack Overflow

From those 248 users:

- **307** questions were posted
- **151** were closed
- **158** were deleted
- **193** scored < 0
- **119** had at least one answer
- **63** scored > 0

By comparison for the rest of the questions asked during this time:

- **543** questions were closed in total
- **578** were deleted
- **729** scored < 0
- **607** had at least one answer
- **418** scored > 0

Of the total IP Addresses, 298 hit some sort of block on Stack Overflow. From those addresses:

- **355** questions were posted here
- **164** were closed
- **172** were deleted
- **211** scored < 0
- **135** had at least one answer
- **81** scored > 0

### Conclusions

In the 30 days prior to the test, approximately 23% of the users asking question on Programmers had hit a block on SO, but during the test this dropped to 20%.  Blocked users asked approximately 24% of questions prior to the test, and 22% of questions during it. While there was a slight increase in the number of questions from blocked IP Addresses, it went from 23% to 25%, I'm not seeing a huge indication that the test on Stack Overflow drove traffic to Programmers.

Comment: thanks! looks like compared to what was a year ago ([stats in Shog's answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7332/31260)) Programmers experience some increase in troublesome questions from blocked SO users, even during test period. As for the drop during the test compared to prior month, that's a real surprise, I expected opposite. Great food for thought, much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

I'm working on something related to this right now, so it's worthwhile to pull the data. More on that in a bit, but first...

- **1380** questions asked here in the last 30 days, from
- **1219** distinct accounts, of which
- **1100** have/had accounts on Stack Overflow
- **184** of whom hit *some kind of block* on Stack Overflow during the past 60 days (this includes not just the quality-ban, but also spam blocks and 4 types of rate-limits).

From those 184 users...

- **227** questions were posted during the past 30 days.
- **152** were closed
- **135** were deleted
- **161** score < 0
- **62** received at least one answer
- **25** score > 0

For comparison,

- **771** questions were closed in total during the past 30 days,
- **636** were deleted,
- **728** score < 0,
- **523** were answered, and
- **323** score > 0

But... that's not the whole story. See, posting here in response to a block on Stack Overflow is a real desperation move - and there are less extreme tactics to try first. Like sockpuppets...

I grabbed the IP addresses associated with those 1380 posts and looked to see how many had been associated with blocked questions on Stack Overflow in the past 60 days. From those 255 IPs,

- **267** questions were posted here during the past 30 days,
- **168** of which were closed,
- **154** of which were deleted,
- **176** of which score < 0,
- **87** of which were answered, and
- **35** of which score > 0

Now, folks share IPs, and hop between networks. IP-based banning isn't a great long-term solution for anything... But if your goal is to slow down folks searching desperately for any text box into which they can type, then it ain't bad. Which is why we've been working on a system for temporarily classifying networks according to the number of bad posts coming from them. I took the *currently-live* data for this and compared it to the questions posted here during the past 2 days:

- **9** questions from potentially "bad" networks
- **4** of these closed
- **5** of these deleted
- **5** scoring < 0
- **2** answered
- **3** upvoted

Total stats for the same time period: 166,47,37,58,30,58.

### Conclusions

Thus far, blocks on SO are a pretty weak predictor for quality. While there is a *massive* overlap between users on both sites, blocked users don't account for a very large chunk of the total here, and the false-positive rate is high.

Network-based tracking is even worse... But there's a caveat: we're *only* tracking networks with problematic posts on Stack Overflow right now, so all of those posts (and users) having issues on Programmers itself don't count. Right now, the network quality signal is used to feed Triage review on Stack Overflow... [Potentially](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251737/triage-and-help-improvement-review-queues-at-sites-other-than-stack-overflow/251744#251744), turning on tracking for Programmers would allow it to do the same thing here, and save a considerable amount of time identifying these questions on *both* sites.

Comment: [Could we please detect troublesome questions using Stack Overflow data and offload them to Triage review for an hour or two?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7257/31260)

Comment: regarding stats, am I reading it correctly that these folks bring us 4-5 delete-worthy questions a day average? "135 were deleted" in the last 30 days

Comment: Somewhere in that range. Out of the 20+ deletable questions y'all get each day.

Comment: understood, thanks. FWIW it feels _very_ differently to moderate ["systemically leaked content"](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6508/31260 "'someone that is very likely unable to ask questions on one site bringing the same poor quality here'") compared to one that flows in organically. It's almost like... like voting to close and delete spam/offensive content. Not _quite_ as weird, but fairly close

Comment: The problem is, you're paranoid about this: plenty of folks asking stupid, OT questions who've never posted anywhere before.

Comment: that's a convenient theory for sure. If only it could explain why I am not paranoid about other delete-worthy questions